# problem with changes GMT( time zone )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, dst

I created a small script to display the time(`UTC-+3.5`). The problem is there that [changes GMT(+4.5, +3.5) in Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Standard_Time) every six months in year, and changes Time is pulled back and forth (`Daylight Saving`)
How i set **yourself clock** with **change GMT in iran**? what do i do? **(now GMT in iran is +4.5)**

**EXAMPLE:** [my code-jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/8/)

```
var int = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);

function clock() {
    var d = calcTime('+4.5')
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = t;
}

function calcTime(offset) {
    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));

    return nd;
}
```

With respect

Comment: Please clerify, you want to automatically adjust to Daylight Savings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/HZmPg/9/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var int = self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);

function clock() {
    var d = calcTime('+4.5')
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = t;
}

function calcTime(offset) {
    d = new Date();
    ds = new Date(); // new Daylight Savings Time object
    ds.setMonth(9); // Set month to september
    ds.setDate(21); // set day to 21st
    if(d > ds){ // if current date is past the daylight savings date minus one from the offset
        offset = eval(offset - 1);
    }
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));

    return nd;
}
</script>

<b id="clock"></b>
```

This works. It will check if the date is currently past September 21st and if it is it will -4.5 from GMT otherwise 3.5

it is not the cleanest code i've ever written, I just modified yours. however you can see how it is done now.

Comment: ALSO be advised, you will want to put in the check for the other end of things. This code will work from sept 21st > dec 31st, however january to march it will see this as 4.5 not 3.5... FYI

Comment: Thanks. but this (Fiddle Example) not show. Please tell me the best way in example

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/HZmPg/11/ *you have to take the quotes around clock() away in `self.setInterval("clock()", 1000);
` i forgot to do that in my fiddle ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HZmPg/15/ This is my last update. My example shows you how to apply a daylight savings conversion. it is not meant to be your cut and paste solution.